# A program that uses switch statements and calculate and display the total price of the selected book type

Tags: java, switch-statement

An online book seller sells four book types for the following prices.

- Book type 1: £ 15.98
- Book type 2: £ 12.50
- Book type 3: £ 11.98
- Book type 4: £ 17.49

Write a program that takes inputs as follows.

- Book type
- No of books

Your program should use switch statements and calculate and display the total price of the selected book type.

So I'm new to java and just learning. I have learnt how to write switch cases in java. But can't quite wrap my head around this. Any hints or ideas are appreciated.

HERE'S WHAT I GOT SO FAR! 
I'm not sure what I did is what the question is asking of me.

```js
import java.util.*;
public class onlineBookstore {
    public static void main (String [] Args)
    {
        Scanner x= new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,price; 
        String book;
        System.out.println("Enter the Book type");
        book = x.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the Number of books");
        book = x.next();
        
        
       switch(book) {
           case "book1" :
            System.out.println("£ 15.98");
            break;
            case "book2" :
            System.out.println("£ 12.50"); 
            break;
            case "book3":
            System.out.println("£ 11.98 ");
            break;
            case "book4":
            System.out.println("£ 17.49");
            break; 
           default :
            System.out.println("INVALID");
       }
        System.out.println("This is the end of the program");
       }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a homework assignment, it is frowned upon here to ask people to do it for you, that is probably why you are getting down-voted. Your question is about switch statements but yet there are none in you code example. You should try something first and ask when you get stuck. I doubt there are no question already answered on Stack Overflow about this subject, so look around! Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: Hey I know
I'm not asking for the whole code, I'm asking for help on how to think to write this code.
Not a homework, studying for a test.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share the detailed info when you ask a question. **1** What do you have ? **2**. What did you try in order to solve the problem? (Question should be concise)

Comment: Hi Vebbie
yeah the question is there
and what i got is also there :)

Comment: Your question is very broad. It is unclear what you don't understand, that's why it seems like you are asking people to do it for you.

Comment: I know thanks.
I don't quite understand how to bring the main part before presenting the cases.
Maybe I'm not just not there yet.

Comment: total price which must be calculated if  for example I enter book type 1 and no of books as 2.
I'm kinda struggling to bring about that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question suggests
This might help you out

```
public class onlineBookstore {
public static void main(String[] Args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String book;
    int noOfBooks;
    System.out.println("Available options are: [book1,book2,book3,book4]");
    System.out.println("Enter the Book type:");
    book = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the Number of books");
    noOfBooks = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (book) {
    case "book1":
        System.out.println("The total price of the selected book type is : " + noOfBooks * 15.98);
        break;
    case "book2":
        System.out.println("The total price of the selected book type is : " + noOfBooks * 12.50);
        break;
    case "book3":
        System.out.println("The total price of the selected book type is : " + noOfBooks * 11.98);
        break;
    case "book4":
        System.out.println("The total price of the selected book type is : " + noOfBooks * 17.49);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("INVALID");
    }
    System.out.println("This is the end of the program");
}
```

}

Further changes can be done on this if you need some more features from your program

Answer (score -2):

THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH VEBBIE.
IM SUCH A NOOB. 
THIS IS THE CODE I GOT IN THE END. AND IT WORKS FLAWLESSLY.

```js
import java.util.*;
public class onlineBookstore {
    public static void main (String [] Args)
    {
        Scanner x= new Scanner(System.in);
        int book;
        System.out.println("Enter the Book type");
        book = x.nextInt();
        int numb;
        System.out.println("Enter the Number of books");
        numb = x.nextInt();
        
       switch(book) {
           case 1 :
            System.out.println("Total price of the book is"+" "+"£"+ numb * 15.98);
            break;
            case 2 :
            System.out.println("Total price of the book is"+" "+"£"+ numb * 12.50); 
            break;
            case 3:
            System.out.println("Total price of the book is"+" "+"£"+ numb * 11.98);
            break;
            case 4 :
            System.out.println("Total price of the book is"+" "+"£"+ numb * 17.49);
            break; 
           default :
            System.out.println("INVALID BOOK TYPE");
       }
       
       }
}
```